# Getting File Attributes(like creation time) in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am working with Apache spark and need to know if its possible to have file creation date and lines as a key value pair while loading text files from a folder in the local system

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this through a customised local file input rdd.

Another answer of mine that create an RDD class from scratch on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950299/distributed-web-crawling-using-apache-spark/29960707#29960707)

If you consider a customised RDD possible, I could update my answer later.

Comment: Hey,Thanks for the response and happy to know its possible.But I am an entry level person(in Spark) and if you can help me with the customised RDD,that would be great.

Comment: Tomorrow morning, it's midnight and iphone is unsuitable to write and edit :(

Comment: oh sure,sleep tight..:)

Comment: Hello,you got something for me?